# Left hand navigation on a modern page within SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, modern-pages, style.css

i am trying to figure out some CSS to widen the left hand navigation on a modern page within SharePoint online. I have been using the alternative CSS settings on the masterpage setting to enter the CSS. So I can trial it.. I have no access to F12 tools to find out what the element is called.

Has anyone done this and have some quick code , i can dig into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a SharePoint modern page, to add CSS/JavaScript code, you need to install [Modern Script Editor web part](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d4b8b3c4-8950-4407-9120-204b80fc35f9/sharepoint-online-best-practice-install-modern-script-editor-web-part-for-sharepoint-online?forum=odspproductsandservicesharing) then add your code into the web part.

Comment: yes i can appreciate that but I have no access to add SPFX web parts in modern... there has to be a way of doing it without adding in script editors. but the CSS has to be correct first before i do anything like that even if i could - so thats why i am testing with alternate CSS...

Comment: Sadly, there doesn't actually have to be a way to do it without adding some kind of SPFX customization, in fact there isn't a way. alternate CSS does nothing on modern pages. The easiest solution is the SPFX web part Kally_MSFT mentioned. If you cannot do that, then you cannot apply custom CSS or JavaScript to modern pages.

Answer (score 0):

I've hidden the left hand navigation using the following code:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
     #sideNavBox {DISPLAY: none} 
     #contentBox {MARGIN-LEFT: 5px}  
</style>
```

So the element is called #sideNavBox

Comment: that did not work when i added this piece of code in the alternative css on the masterpage setting.. SharePoint online.... any other ideas ?